# zip counterpart to tar -d

Tags: zip, tar

Decades ago, I relied heavily on `tar czf ...` to create snapshots of sprawling work.  However, the rest of the world runs on Windows and `zip`.  My experience in those past decades is that using `unzip` on `*.tar.gz`/`*.tgz` files was been disastorous.  Incomplete snapshots that were merrily made, path length problems, etc.

Since, then, I've moved to command-line `zip`.  It has its merits, but it's missing one crucial operation.  That is the `tar -d` option, which checks the contents of a `*.tgz` snapshot against the uncompressed source files.  I've slogged through the opening of `*.zip` files into correspondingly named `*.unzip` subfolders so that I can apply `diff`.  Since Vim can descend into text files within a `*.zip` snapshot, I sometimes use Vim's `diff` function to compare with the unzipped source file.  That only works for text files, and Vim won't descend into a nested `*.zip` file.  Regardless of whether I explicitly unzip a snapshot or use Vim to avoid doing so, however, both approaches are relatively laborious.

It has been a long time, and zip doesn't seem to have evolved to include a counterpart to `tar -d`.  Do people just handraulically do what I do above or is there an easier way?  I use Cygwin rather than Linux per se, and I prefer something from the command line.

Comment: Cygwin bases on GNU/Linux sources and in Linux world zip is not used that often. More common are combinations of tar+gzip or tar+bzip2. And as usually in open source systems programs that are not widely used do not "evolve". May be you should consider using a real backup programs for saving your work or create a local repo using `git`. Via git creating diffs between two states would be easier as it is directly integrated in git so you don't have to uncompress anything at all.

Comment: I often have to share files with Windows-only users.  My environment often consists of a highly restricted non-administrator account, highly restrictive group policies, and highly restrictive barriers to just about anything.  It was hard enough to get Cygwin, and almost impossible to keep it up-to-date.  For now, I'd like to work with what I have.